# Error while calling asp classic function from javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

I am trying to call classic ASP function from jQuery ajax but it is giving 404 error. I want to return records inJSON in this javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../dbFile.asp/GetAllRecords",
    data: {"Id"="10"},
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    success: function(result){
       alert("success");
    }
});
return false;
});
```

and my vb script function in asp classic file is

```
Function GetAllRecords()
    dim cmd, rs
    set cmd=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = 4
    cmd.CommandText = "GetAllRecords"
    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    set rs=cmd.Execute()
    set GetAllRecords= rs
    set rs=nothing
    set cmd=nothing
End Function
```

Please guide, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call a classic ASP page as if you're calling ASP.NET WebMethod. You can call it by passing a parameter in Querystring, e.g.

```
url: "../dbFile.asp?Action=GetAllRecords",
```

And in your ASP code do something like

```
If Request("Action") = "GetAllRecords"
   Response.Write GetAllRecords()
   Response.End
End If
```

Note: For this to work your `GetAllRecords()` function need to return actual string with JSON or XML, right now it retruns a Recordset. You need to loop thru recordset, building string in the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I managed to solve my problem by using aspjson liberary by calling asp page and returning data in form of json.